# Using a Riemann sum to (effectively) prove a $p$-series

Tags: calculus

[image: Picture of Problem]

**Attempt at a textual explanation of the problem (if for whatever reason you don't want to view the picture):** I have to use a Riemann sum for the function $1/x^2$ on the interval $[1,n]$ to show that it's less than $1 +$ definite integral of $1/x^2\,dx$. Finally, I have to conclude that the infinite sum is at most $2$.

I'm presenting this problem tomorrow, and though I think I can justify it using the integral, I'm not sure how to demonstrate that using a Riemann sum.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. For $n\geq 1$, for $p>1$ consider the [lower Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) of the decreasing function $f(x)=1/x^p$ over the interval $[1,n]$ with respect to the uniform partition $1<2<\dots<n$.

Comment: I guess this was a dumb question, it cancels out the [1x1 area](https://i.imgur.com/GJvIkIy.jpg?1), right? (I had this work before I asked the question, was just thinking it was included for some reason) I'm still unsure about the conclusion that it is at most 2, because doing integration, I found that it converges at 1?

Comment: The Riemann sum gives you the inequality  without the $1$s (on both sides). Actually you can't use the reimann sum on $[0,n]$ because $1/x^2$ is unbounded  near $0$.